# Is it possible to check in a powershell script, that a .cmd runs?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I'm creating a powershell script, that starts at some points some .cmd scripts. Until they are not done, the script should wait. I need a method i can check the runtime of a .cmd script with. 
Here is the code:

```
$sortDocs = @(Get-ChildItem "D:\test\WZKTest\SortFolder\*\*")

foreach($item in $sortDocs) 
{
    if($item.name -match "I.7z")
    {
        sz x -o"$inlandFolder" $item.FullName  -r
    } elseif($item.name -match "A.7z")
    {
        sz x -o"$auslandFolder" $item.FullName  -r
    }
}

Invoke-Item "D:\ODDA\Workflow\Wasserzaehlerkarten\wasserzaehlerkarten_10092018_final_A.cmd"
Invoke-Item "D:\ODDA\Workflow\Wasserzaehlerkarten\wasserzaehlerkarten_10092018_final_I.cmd"
```

After the Invoke method, should it wait, until the 2 .cmd runs.

Comment: if you use `Start-Process` instead of `Invoke-Item` you can use the `-Wait` parameter to have the cmdlet wait until the item has finished running.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thank you, that was it. Please write as answer and i vote it up :)

Comment: you are most welcome ... glad to help a bit! [*grin*] ///// as for an "answer" - from what i can tell, there are lots of answers on the subject already, so i don't see any need for an official answer. thank you for the offer, tho!

Comment: If running them concurrently is possible, `Invoke-Command -AsJob` could be used with code to wait for them all to complete.